# How do you invert the colors in a stencil drawing so that the result looks otherwise identical to the original?

Tags: drawing, black, white-space, technique, portrait

I have a stencil image of Karl Marx. The subject is mostly white on a black background. However, I would like to create another version of it where the subject is black on a white background. **I thought that simply inverting the colors would do the trick, but it ends up looking terrible** (see below) and not recognizable. This was puzzling.

Does anyone know how to do this correctly so the look is exactly the same and only the subject/background colors are flipped?

[image: karl-marx-stencil]

[image: karl-marx-stencil-inverted]

Comment: The problem is that the brain interprets dark as shadow, so when you invert it you're getting all the wrong signals. I don't know any way to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You must *reconstruct the island* where the head is to recover at least the edge on which the figure-ground effect is built without altering it.

[image]

Or, after reconstructing the head shape, change the background color:

[image]

There's a similar problem in [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/115912/120647)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think inverting will work - it has clearly failed as shown by your example. Here's a different approach. Start with the original photograph (there's a copy on Wikipedia)

In Photoshop, remove the background using the Select and Mask workspace

[image]

Create a new layer from visible (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+E)

Convert the layer into a Smart Object and apply the Cutout filter

Add a threshold adjustment layer effect

Here's the result

[image]

The nice thing about using a Smart Object and Threshold adjustment layer effect is that they are non-destructive, and you can adjust the settings to get different results.

For example, here I adjust the Threshold, and the Cutout filter levels:

[image]

It's also possible to add additional filters for more refinement of missing details. Here I add a Poster Edges filter, and fix some holes left in the arm by creating another layer and painting on it.

[image]